# How to assign names in a MATLAB loop

Tags: matlab, loops

I am having problems looping in MATLAB.

```
%% Getting Stocks
stocks = hist_stock_data('01012013','07112014','GDXJ', 'JDST', 'GLD');
```

This is the chunk I want to loop

```
% STOCK #1
stocks(1,1).Date=datenum(stocks(1,1).Date); 
stocks(1,1).Date = stocks(1,1).Date(end:-1:1); 
stocks(1,1).AdjClose = stocks(1,1).AdjClose(end:-1:1);
GDXJ=stocks(1,1).AdjClose;

% STOCK #2
stocks(1,2).Date=datenum(stocks(1,2).Date); 
stocks(1,2).Date = stocks(1,2).Date(end:-1:1); 
stocks(1,2).AdjClose = stocks(1,2).AdjClose(end:-1:1); 
JDST=stocks(1,2).AdjClose;

% STOCK #3
stocks(1,3).Date=datenum(stocks(1,3).Date); 
stocks(1,3).Date = stocks(1,3).Date(end:-1:1); 
stocks(1,3).AdjClose = stocks(1,3).AdjClose(end:-1:1); 
GLD=stocks(1,3).AdjClose;
```

The only problem I am having is assigning names so that I extract the vector from `stocks` unto my workspace. Here is what i currently have:

```
%% Extract number of Columns
[row, col] = size(stocks);

%% Different Loop
for ii = 1:col
stocks(1,ii).Date=datenum(stocks(1,ii).Date);
stocks(1,ii).Date = stocks(1,ii).Date(end:-1:1);
stocks(1,ii).AdjClose = stocks(1,ii).AdjClose(end:-1:1);
[Prices] = stocks(1,ii).AdjClose;
end
```

How can I assign names to the `[Prices]` vector above so that i end up extracting `GDXJ`, `JDST`, and `GLD` from `stocks` ?

Comment: Assuming that your `[Prices]` will only have the `GDXJ`,`JDST`, `GLD`....you can check the `stocks` to see if the element you are interested in is an alpha. The following `s = isstrprop('GDXJ', 'alpha')` will return `s = [1 1 1 1]` logical. If you `all(s)` is true, you get it extracted ? Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you -

```
%% Getting Stocks
stocks = hist_stock_data('01012013','07112014','GDXJ', 'JDST', 'GLD');

%% Extract number of Columns
[row, col] = size(stocks);

%% Different Loop
for ii = 1:col
    stocks(1,ii).Date=datenum(stocks(1,ii).Date);
    stocks(1,ii).Date = stocks(1,ii).Date(end:-1:1);
    stocks(1,ii).AdjClose = stocks(1,ii).AdjClose(end:-1:1);
end

fnms = fieldnames(stocks); %// get fieldnames
datac = struct2cell(stocks); %// convert struct to cell
[GDXJ,JDST,GLD] = deal(datac{strcmp(fnms,'AdjClose'),:}); %// get only the relevant 
                                                    %// fieldname data from the cell
```

Or this after the for-loop ends -

```
datac = arrayfun(@(x) stocks(x).AdjClose,1:col,'Uniform',0);
[GDXJ,JDST,GLD] = deal(datac{:});
```

Comment: @Rime Awesome! Cheers :)